# Efficiently convert an area to matrix in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, matrix, sprite-kit, uikit

I am new to Sprite Kit. I am looking for a way to convert an area to a matrix, and put objects inside the matrix.

Let us assume, I have a *SKSpriteNode *matrix* of size 100 x 100 i.e height and width both 100.I want to turn it to a 10x10 matrix out of this 100 x 100 size. I have to turn this to a matrix, and put the objects within this matrix of size 10x10.

What is the best way of converting this to a grid, so all other objects can be placed of a size of 10 x 10 anywhere in the matrix?

In Objective C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create object and give it properties column, row.

This is my algorithm of creating puzzle game something like Candy crush :D

```
-(void)createRandomly {

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {

            float dimension = self.frame.size.width / columns;
            int randomBubble = arc4random() % valuesCount;
            Bubble *node = [[Bubble alloc] initWithRow:row column:col size:CGSizeMake(dimension, dimension)];
            [self.scene addChild:node];
        }
    }
}
```

I Would recomend you to watch this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpFwM8CZ10U&spfreload=10

I think this tutorial will help you better :)